# How can I write more than 255 characters into a CSV cell using c programming?

Tags: c, excel, csv

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ( )
{
   FILE *OutputFile;
   char arr[1000] = "Hello I am writing some string into this cell which is more than 255 characters but I couldnot print this through CSV file please help me to get rid of the problem I do not why excel is allowing 255 characters only in one cell please write a solution to overcome this problem your help is very much appreciated";

   OutputFile = fopen( "excel.csv", "w+");

   fprintf ( OutputFile, "%s", arr);

   fclose(OutputFile);
}
```

Now if I run this program the out put in the first cell is only confined to 255 characters. I.e.

> "Hello I am writing some string into this cell which is more than 255 characters but I couldnot print this through CSV file please help me to get rid of the problem I do not why excel is allowing 255 characters only in one cell please write a solution to"

The remaining string is missing.

How to get the whole string arr printed on a single cell which contains 311 characters?

Comment: You are most likely corrupting your *Excel* data file when you attempt to write formatted character data to what may be a binary section of the excel file.

Comment: Are you sure the actual string you are trying to write doesn't have a `,` ? Why don't you show us the actual program you are trying?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think it is a normal csv file that excel can read. Shouldn't have any binary section.

Comment: This is more of an Excel issue than a C one, and a quite well-known one at that - I think you can mess about with encodings (cp1252?). I'll add the Excel tag so an expert there can help. Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Show the file you've got, and the file you want to get.

Comment: Running that code compiled with GCC I get a csv with the full string in first cell, which loads correctly in Excel

Comment: It is an excel issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with Excel not *reading* more than 255 characters into a single cell. (I am *guessing* you are using Excel, from the filename you used.)

If you open the `excel.csv` file *in a text editor*, the full text is in there, so your program works correctly.